# U-boot 2018.09 : Getting list of compiled files and configuration options for SPL, U-boot

Tags: u-boot, kbuild

I am trying to study the execution flow of SPL and U-boot proper specifically for BeagleBone Black(am335x_boneblack_defconfig) by browsing through the source code.

1. How can i generate the list of source files which gets compiled into U-boot proper(u-boot.img) and SPL(MLO) binaries? If i get a list of files which gets compiled for SPL and U-boot separately, then i can use cscope to browse through the code. ( make cscope just generates the list of files which gets compiled for U-boot proper, and it includes many files which are not compiled into binary )
2. How can i generate the configuration macros(CONFIG_*) which are used during build process of U-boot and SPL binaries? Is include/generated/autoconf.h containing the macros used for U-boot.
3. What does u-boot.cfg and spl/u-boot.cfg contain? Are these the configuration macros used for building U-boot and SPL respectively?

Answer (score 2):

The files that are compiled can be seen while u-boot sources are getting compiled, as verbose, when you perform the following.

1. make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} distclean
2. make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} am335x_evm_defconfig
3. make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC}

Comment: How can i view the CONFIG_* macros used during compilation of U-boot and SPL ?

Comment: @SreekeshSreelal you just read the *.config file to view CONFIG_* macros, you can use cat.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer what about SPL? Is there a similar file for SPL as well?

Comment: all bootloader configuration appears in one config file.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer all the object files generated for SPL appears in spl/ directory inside U-boot sources. Only difference while building SPL is that the build system defines a macro CONFIG_SPL_BUILD, which is used in conditional compilation directives to compile-in SPL specific stuff.